# Gmaps4rails map doesn't load with zurb foundation initialised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, gmaps4rails

I've spent many hours trying to solve this to no avail. Basically I'm integrating the gmaps4rails gem with a rails project, and it appears to be conflicting with zurb's foundation JS. In my application.js file I have the following:

```
//= require modernizr-2.0.6
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require jquery.ui.core
//= require jquery.ui.autocomplete
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

This works fine everywhere else on my site, but no map loads. However as soon as I remove the line:

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

it works fine (but obviously everything else that relies on the foundation JS breaks).

1. How would I go about debugging this?
2. Related to gmaps4rails - do I still need the acts_as_gmappable and def gmaps4rails_address in my model if all my records are already geocoded? When records are created they are geocoder with the rails geocoder gem, then the address attributes and lat/lng are all stored in the db
3. Should my application.js be in the header, or above the closing body tag (above the gmaps4rails yield tag). If I put it in the footer, that means I can't use inline JS anywhere on the site right, since it would be occuring before the js libraries are loaded?

Any help will be much appreciated, I'm completely stuck!

Comment: Also, both with and without the zurb initialisation line, there are no errors in the JS console

Comment: Managed to fix it, not quite sure how but with the line         (function($) { $(document).foundation(); })(jQuery); above the gmaps4rails 'yield' script it worked

Comment: sounds like a jquery conflict. you might want to look into how they avoid that by looking up "jquery the right way wordpress".